# carton: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, perl, cpan

I am trying to work with Perl for the first time and I am having some difficulty installing [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton). I am following [this guide](https://erco.xyz/doc/installation.html) to install Erco.

I am on Ubuntu 14. I have build-essential. When I run

```
carton install
```

I get

```
bash: carton: command not found
```

When I ran `cpan Carton` it seemed to work, but `which carton` comes up with nothing. Now when I run `cpan Carton` my output is:

```
Reading '/home/<username>/.cpan/Metadata'
Reading '/home/<username>/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Reading '/home/<username>/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
Database was generated on Tue, 02 Feb 2016 18:17:03 GMT
HTTP::Date not available
..............
New CPAN.pm version (v2.10) available.
[Currently running version is v2.00]
You might want to try
install CPAN
reload cpan
to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
the current session.
```

..................................................Killed

I tried running `install CPAN` but it responds with

```
install: missing destination file operand after 'CPAN'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably when you do `cpan` its not doing configure correct `Carton`

I think you should try `cpanm Carton`

cpanminus (cpanm) is an attempt to make a zero-configuration client that automatically does the right thing for most users.

Comment: Thanks PoX! I tried your suggestion and it didn't work with just `cpanm Carton` but `sudo cpanm Carton` seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Without sudo, cpanm will install into, I believe, `$HOME/perl5/bin` so add that to the beginning of your $PATH.